# How to make links in email direct and non-trackable

Tags: mailing, hyperlinks

We are sending emails containing links which are redirecting through civi. We need them to go direct to the website. (Our civi is not public facing). All articles / questions i have seen are about making urls trackable, we need the opposite.

Any link added to a message template is creating a url that runs through our server. This happens regardless of how email is sent, single email, bulk email etc.

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Could you post an example of a rewritten URL from a single email?  CiviCRM doesn't rewrite URLs on non-CiviMail emails - but you may be using a third-party SMTP provider that does.

Comment: Hi Jon... yes the Transactional Email extension found to be the source of the probelm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adding of trackable urls is down to an extension called Transactional Email. This was installed so we could records bounces on single emails going out (which is only set up in default for bulk mail). The extension adds tracking links across the whole install. Disabling this extension stopped it redirecting urls through our servers.  Thanks to Bails at Circle Interactive for helping find the answer.

Comment: this was an extension we made. if you want to sponsor a fix so this is 'configurable' in the extension, or provide a PR, we would be happy to include it assuming we can find a way to still track Bounces while not tracking URLs

Comment: Thansk Pete, we may well do this once we have our new install comfortably bedded in.

Answer (score 4):

Parvez is rigth!

I want to add: In your case, when you will never ever want to use trackable links, you can switch them off in the CiviMail component settings: Uncheck the options "Enable click-through tracking by default" and "Enable open tracking by default"

Comment: thanks Detlev... had not spotted that setting! However they are both currently unchecked already ....

Comment: I have tried enabling/disabling the two settings and saving and the behaviour remains the same. Links still directed through civi....  :(

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off tracking in the "Advanced Mailing Options" on the final step, assuming your using to send. I've attached a screen shot for reference.

[image: Mosaico]

On the Tracking tab, you can untick "Track Click Throughs" to stop URLs going via CiviCRM. To clarify you will then lose the ability to see tracking information on the mailing reports.

Comment: Thanks. Its works for mailings but not for single emails sent direct off a contact record or any email sent from under a case. ..  Is there a way to make a global change so no urls sent out in any email regardless of mechanism are redirected through Civi?  We send many emails using the 'less than 50' off a search for example...